# Error 403 Forbidden HTTP request to download HTML

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, http-status-code-403

I need some help to download the data from a site

I do know whats is wrong in my code, i see a lot of helps but i cant solve

I was trying to acess the site data for get the economic calendar information,

Here is my code:

```
namespace Adquire_dados
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object webRequest;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetRequest("https://br.investing.com/economic-calendar/");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        async static void GetRequest(string url)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);


                using (HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    using (HttpContent content = httpResponse.Content)
                    {
                        string mycontent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(mycontent);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the result that i Have:

```
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Does the user that is running nginx have access (NTFS security permissions) to the files/folders of the application?

Comment: How I can check this?

I was trying this code by follow some internet tutorials

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nginx+403 ?

Comment: I was looking but the solutions is just  for linux system, Im'm using visual studio

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Trace results by putting URL into an IE and capture the headers that are sent by browser in request.  Then add missing headers to your  c# application.

Comment: I find this Header:
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Thu, 21 Mar 2019 17:27:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 71618
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.8
Set-Cookie: ses_id=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; p

And what i need to do now?